# Does SlimBox2 support PNG?

Tags: jquery, slimbox

I tried to open a PNG file in Firefox using Slimbox2:

```
<a href="images/project3.png" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">image #1</a>
```

It didn't work, it just opened the picture.

then I cahnged PNG to Jpg and it worked.

Does SlimBox2 support PNG?

Header:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
    <title>New Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/slimbox2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/global.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/home.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.corner.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/slimbox2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/custom.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it supports PNG files. I would look to make sure you have a project3.png file in your images folder.

What happens when you click on the link? Nothing at all or do you get a white box with the ajax "please wait" graphic?

Is this a project that gets compiled and copied to another folder? If so the image may not be copied.